# How to fix ClassNotFoundException thrown by configuration @Import in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm working on a Maven-based Spring Boot App that just connects to our databases and generates reports based on the data. The main method looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name","reports");

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active","JTEST");

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ReportsRunner.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .bannerMode(Mode.OFF)
                .run(args);
    }
```

When it gets to the Run call, the following error(s) generate:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class[com.company.dept.reports.ReportsRunner]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:398) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar!/:3.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar!/:3.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar!/:3.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:150) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar!/:3.0.6]
        at com.company.dept.reports.ReportsRunner.main(ReportsRunner.java:37) ~[classes!/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[reports.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[reports.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[reports.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[reports.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [com.company.dept.postgres.PostGresAppConfig]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:333) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:390) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:278) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:301) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:102) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:81) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:280) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.dept.postgres.PostGresAppConfig
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:432) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149) ~[reports.jar:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:323) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:390) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:278) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:301) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:102) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:81) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:280) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        ... 19 more
```

A BeanDefinitionStoreException triggered by an IllegalArgumentException, triggered by a ClassNotFoundException.

So it seems like it's unable to find a class. PostGresAppConfig is from a separate jar/package that I've added as a dependency to this project. It looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.dept.postgres.configuration"})
public class PostGresAppConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    @Bean
    public PostGresAppConfig postGresAppConfig(){
        return new PostGresAppConfig();
    }
}
```

I believe it's some kind of issue with this file, because when I remove its import from the the config file, the error goes away:

```
//This throws no errors
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:reports.properties")
@Import({
        BasicCoreConfiguration.class, //internal
        ReportsConfigurationDev.class, //internal
        ReportsConfigurationTest.class, //internal
        ReportsConfigurationProd.class}) //internal
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.dept.reports.runner",
        "com.company.dept.beans.utilities",
        "com.company.dept.beans.errorHandling",
        "com.company.dept.foundation.service",
        "com.company.dept.foundation.configuration.service",
        "com.company.dept.postgres.service"})
public class ReportsCommonConfiguration {
```

```
//This throws errors
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:reports.properties")
@Import({
        PostGresAppConfig.class,//external
        BasicCoreConfiguration.class, //internal
        ReportsConfigurationDev.class, //internal
        ReportsConfigurationTest.class, //internal
        ReportsConfigurationProd.class}) //internal
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.dept.reports.runner",
        "com.company.dept.beans.utilities",
        "com.company.dept.beans.errorHandling",
        "com.company.dept.foundation.service",
        "com.company.dept.foundation.configuration.service",
        "com.company.dept.postgres.service"})
public class ReportsCommonConfiguration {
```

Just not sure what's causing this behavior. Maybe something to do with trying to import a configuration from an external jar/dependency? The other imported classes are from inside this project.

I tried finding other questions related to this set of errors but didn't have much luck. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: There is no difference in importing an internal or external dependency in the end it is one classpath. If it cannot be found the dependency isn't there, what is the scope of the dependency, how are you running/building this.

Comment: This dependency has system scope, since I had to manually add the jar to the project. The Pom entry looks like: 

`  <dependency>

   <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>

   <artifactId>postgres</artifactId>

   <version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <scope>system</scope>

   <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/postgres-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>`
I'm building the project' with the normal `mvn package` command

Comment: system scoped dependency aren't included in  your project by default.

Comment: Okay so I added the dependency through the `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>` command, which installs the jar in the local repo, then I removed the scope and systempath tags so that Maven looks in the local repo by default. Started getting a different error about the dependency jar not being able to find its parent POM but I think I fixed that, so I think I'm good now, no longer seeing the above error. Thank you so much @M.Deinum